# How to select left most vertices in UV using python?

Tags: python, uv

I am trying to select vertices/vertex loop in left most direction or top most direction of a UV island using python but I am getting no where.

[image]

I have found this code by batFINGER, which selects top most vertex in viewport.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix

space = 'LOCAL'  # or 'GLOBAL'
find = 'MAX' # or 'MIN'
TOL = 1e-7
ob = bpy.context.object
M = ob.matrix_world if space == 'GLOBAL' else Matrix()
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
verts = sorted(bm.verts, key=lambda v: (M @ v.co).z)

bm.select_flush(False)
#bm.select_flush_mode()
z = (M @ verts[-1 if find == 'MAX' else 0].co).z
for v in verts:
    v.select = abs((M @ v.co).z - z) < TOL
bm.select_flush(True)    


bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the image you provided, it seems you want to select uvs that are close to the leftmost considering a epsilon value.

The script proposed below does the following:

Get all uvs from a bmesh

Sort them accordingly to the wanted axis

Select them until coordinate delta from the top/bottom/left/right most is under an epsilon value.

Code below with details in comments:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# depending on the wanted axis and orientation (TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT)
# return a lambda to access the good coordinate and sorting order (ascending or descending)
def get_sort_key(axis):
    if axis == 'TOP':
        return lambda uv: uv.uv[1], True
    if axis == 'BOTTOM':
        return lambda uv: uv.uv[1], False
    if axis == 'LEFT':
        return lambda uv: uv.uv[0], False
    if axis == 'RIGHT':
        return lambda uv: uv.uv[0], True

# in edit mode...

# get the active object
object = bpy.context.object

# get a bmesh from its data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(object.data)

# get active uv layer
uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.active

# get all uvs
# uvs are in face loops and accessed in the face loop elements by the uv layer key
uvs = [l[uv_layer] for f in bm.faces for l in f.loops]

# get access function and sorting order depending on the wanted axis
key_func, reversed = get_sort_key('TOP')

# sort elements
uvs = sorted(uvs, key = key_func, reverse = reversed)

EPSILON = 0.001

# take the first coordinate value for comparison
first_co = key_func(uvs[0])

# loop over the uvs
for uv in uvs:
    # get the coordinate value
    co = key_func(uv)
    # select if close from the first element
    uv.select = abs(first_co - co) <= EPSILON

# update selections back to the object mesh data
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(object.data)
```

Comment: works perfectly. Thank you!